# Maven NAR plugin + Spring boot in webapp, loading .nar artifact in Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat, maven-nar-plugin

I've managed to add platform dependencies to `war` and generated by `maven-nar-plugin` jni artifact into `WEB-INF/lib/`.

But the problem is: added artifact has `.nar` extension while `WebappClassLoaderBase` adds only `.jar`s to its internal class repositories, so my jni bridge is not loaded and class is inaccessible leading to   `ClassNotFoundException`.

What are my options here? I assume it's possible to

1. somehow change artifact extension on `spring-boot:repackage`?
2. add this custom artifact to classloader repositories?

Which would be better and how would I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've ended up with `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```
<build>
...
<plugins>
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <goals>
           <goal>copy</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <artifactItems>
             <artifactItem>
               <groupId>${dep.groupId}</groupId>
               <artifactId>${dep.artifactId}</artifactId>
               <version>${dep.version}</version>
               <type>nar</type>
               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
               <destFileName>${dep.artifactId}-${dep.version}.jar</destFileName>
             </artifactItem>
           </artifactItems>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
</build>
```

But still, there is a problem with redeployments to deal with, so if you realy want to do this, here is the way, but you probably don't need it that hard.